# cardinality of maximum antichains in power set posets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $\mathcal{P}(S)$ be the power set of a non empty set $S$. Consider the poset $\succ$ for the inclusion relation over the elements of $\mathcal{P}(S)$ (which is equivalently represented by a single source single sink DAG).

is there a known result for the cardinality of maximal antichain of $\succ$ ?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry. I've edited the question.

Comment: Sperner's theorem says that if $S$ is finite, with $|S|=n$, the largest anti-chain is of size $$\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$$

Comment: @bof I am interested in a number $k$ s.t. there is an antichain of size $k$ but no antichain of size $k+1$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks. I was struggling in understanding the theorem. Not after reading this http://theoremoftheweek.wordpress.com/2010/10/10/theorem-37-sperners-lemma/#comment-5208

Comment: The word you were looking for is *maximum*, not *maximal*.